# Looking for a new bike, any tips for buying a good bike?

Tags: mountain-bike

So as the winter is coming and I have never ridden with a bicycle to work in winter I need a bike that can be fast, but at the same time safe for winter. I have heard that there are some winter tires for bikes, do they really work?  Any tips on those too?

Probably some of you are commuting to work with the bike a long time now and I hope I can get some good tips on that. 
To be honest, I have never ridden a bike to work, so any kind of tips will be appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit broad.  Search this site on commuting and winter.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say where you are located, so it is bit hard to tell what your specific requirements might be, but you do make a distinction around 'winter riding'.  So let's assume you mean cold, perhaps treated roads, perhaps snow, perhaps ice.

For tires, while there's some tension between 'wide' and 'fast', I would suggest 32mm or wider, if they'll fit in your frame, fork, and brakes.  Something with tread if you plan on riding in the wet or on treated (gravel-covered) roads.  If you expect to encounter ice, you may want studs.

Another unknown is time of day and what the lighting conditions will be.  In my opinion the single biggest safety improvement you can make is to ensure you are visible in darkness and in low light, to drivers who are in a hurry, tired, and often distracted.

I would recommend highly visible (hi-viz yellow and orange) clothing, many reflectors (especially moving reflectors, such as ankle bands and spoke reflectors), a bright, multi-mode, rechargeable stroboscopic rear light; a bright, constant-beam, rechargeable front light, and an auxiliary stroboscopic white front light.  There are many good choices out there.

There are also helmets with integrated safety lights available; these work well in my experience.

If you are looking for specific product recommendations I'm sure many folks can provide them.

Comment: I don't think I mentioned a specific product, however I did mention specific product characteristics which I believe, based on extensive experience, to be important.